# ¿Cómo puedo evitar omitir una variable al declarar una condicional en donde no exista x elemento en una lista?

Tags: python

Recientemente realicé una pregunta muy similar, pero no conseguí explicarme correctamente.

Trato de realizar una operación algebraica `x³ * x²`, de tal modo que dicha expresión algebraica siempre toma el mismo índice y diferente exponente.

En la pregunta anterior realicé una comparativa dinámica, de una lista (`list1`)estática con otra dinámica (`list2`) y se añadía a una tercera como resultado (`resultado`).
De tal manera que la lista uno era:

```
lista1 = ['pulpo', 'gato', 'perro', 'lobo', 'pez']
```

La `lista2` equivalía a la cantidad de elementos de dicha lista, pero con shuffle eran revueltos para no repetir la posición numérica.
Y en la lista tres `result` se unían ambas listas, de tal manera que quedaba así:

```
2pulpo, 3gato, 1perro, 4lobo, 0pez
```

Pero en este caso, de una lista:

```
letras = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
```

El índice debe ser elegido al azar y siempre debe ser el mismo, en una cantidad iterada de veces, esa cantidad que debe ser iterada, debe ser en un rango del 2 al 6. Asimismo, la longitud del índice numérico a elegir, debe ser aleatorio en un rango del 0 a la longitud que tiene la lista `letras`:

```
letras = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']

aleatorio = randint(2,4)
indice_estatico=randint(0, len(letras)-1)
for i in range(aleatorio):
        letra_elegida = choice(letras[indice_estatico])
```

En lo anterior, se añade el -1, porque me imprime la longitud contando desde el 0. Visualmente son 9, pero eso excede la cantidad numérica contada desde el índice numérico que comienza desde el 0, de tal modo que son 8.

La potencia tiene que cumplir con la longitud que tome el índice numérico de la expresión algebraica:

```
potencia = []
up=0 #Contador
for i in range(aleatorio): #La variable aleatorio está definida en la cantidad de veces a iterar el ciclo
    up+=1
    potencia_aleatoria = randint(2, 10) #La potencia puede tomar cantidades numéricas del 2 al 10
    if potencia_aleatoria not in potencia:
            potencia.append(potencia_aleatoria)
```

El código me funciona correctamente, a excepción por la condición `potencia_aleatoria not in potencia`, debido a que al momento de que una iteración no cumple con la condición, esta la omite y de esta forma reduce la longitud de potencias que cada elemento debe llevar. Y como consecuencia a esto, me arroja **IndexError: list index out of range**.

Lo que busco es que me arroje esto:

```
b4 · b9 · b3 · b6 #Índice estático (los índices pueden ser 2 hasta el 6) pero potencias aleatorias deben coincidir con los índices y ser todas diferentes.
```

Lo que **NO** busco es:

```
a5 · b4 · c0 · d6 · e7 · f1 · g8 · h3 · i2
```

Código completo:

```
letras = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
result = []
potencia = []
aleatorio = randint(2,4)
indice_estatico=randint(0, len(letras)-1)
up=0
for i in range(aleatorio):
    up+=1
    potencia_aleatoria = randint(2, 10)
    if potencia_aleatoria not in potencia:
            potencia.append(potencia_aleatoria)
    letra_elegida = choice(letras[indice_estatico])
    result.append(f'{letra_elegida}{potencia[up-1]}')
```

¿Cómo puedo solucionar la omisión de la variable `potencia_aleatoria` por incumplir la condicional antes mencionada y evitar que el rango se haga más pequeño?

De antemano agradezco mucho su apoyo. Saludos!

Comment: podrías poner un ejemplo de lo que quieres como resultado?, no he entendido bien tu problema

Comment: Lo puse: Lo que NO busco es:
`a5 · b4 · c0 · d6 · e7 · f1 · g8 · h3 · i2`. Lo que busco es: `b4 · b9 · b3 · b6`

Comment: Al ejecutar el código he obtenido ese resultado

Comment: Ejecútalo un par de veces

Comment: Lo he hecho y lo que note es que el numero de elementos variaba, esto por la variable `aleatorio`

Comment: Por eso, es lo que expliqué

Comment: Lo que quiero evitar es que cuando la condición `potencia_aleatoria not in potencia` cumple con que no se tiene que repetir un número almacenado en la lista `potencia`, cuando el número se omite, la longitud se reduce, por ende, la longitud de dicha lista, no coincide con la variable `aleatorio`. ¿Cómo corrijo eso?

Comment: No sumes 1 siempre, solo hazlo cuando se añada el elemento. Halle la solución y la estoy probando con un `while True` en un momento pongo la respuesta

Comment: Vaya, xd gracias. Sí funcionó, debí haber hecho un ciclo while

Comment: Sí funciona, pero volvemos al mismo problema, la condicional `if not....` deja de tener sentido, debido a que se imprimen números repetidos

Comment: mira la respuesta :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como dije en mi comentario, solo debes de sumar 1 a la variable `up` si agregas un elemento a la lista, por cierto es recomendable incrementar la variable al final y no al comienzo. También podemos evitar *recalcular* algunos valores. Algo que se me olvidaba mencionar era que el resultado solo lo debes agregar en caso el número no se repita, por lo que debe de ir dentro del `if`.

```py
# while True:
letras = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
result = []
potencia = []

aleatorio = randint(2,4)
indice_estatico=randint(0, len(letras)-1)
letra_elegida = choice(letras[indice_estatico])
up=0

for i in range(aleatorio):
    potencia_aleatoria = randint(2, 10)
    if potencia_aleatoria not in potencia:
        potencia.append(potencia_aleatoria)
        result.append(f'{letra_elegida}{potencia[up]}')
        up+= 1
```

También lo puedes hacer con un `while`

```py
#...

while up in range(aleatorio):
    potencia_aleatoria = randint(2, 10)

    if potencia_aleatoria not in potencia:
        potencia.append(potencia_aleatoria)
        result.append(f'{letra_elegida}{potencia[up]}')
        up+= 1
```

Para este caso el `while` tiene mucho más sentido ya que en este caso se repetirá el ciclo hasta que la lista se llene con los elementos requerido, lo que no pasa con el `for`

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo entendí mejor. Ya vi donde está mi error. Gracias @Christian!